# How to use tcp pseudo device to check if docker-compose service is available?

Tags: bash

I have a `kafka` service listening on port `9092`, and I want to create an automated script that will check to see if `kafka` is up and listening before moving on to creating schemas.  I was messing around with something like `bash -c '</dev/tcp/kafka/9092 &>/dev/null'` but I wasn't able to get something working.

I'd like to be able to have a `while <port not available> sleep 5` type statement to put in my script if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is handled by the system service manager (e.g: `systemd` or `init.d`), check the servcies status :

```
# your options may vary if the service is installed as a user service:
systemctl status kafka

service kafka status
```

---

There are several ways to check if some process is listening on a given port :

for local processes, use netsat or ss :

```
netstat -tlnp | grep ':9092'

# netstat options :
# t: list tcp sockets (add 'u' if you also want udp sockets)
# l: list listening sockets
# n: don't try to turn ips or ports into hostnames or known
# p: show pid (if you can access that process details;
#              you may need to sudo if you want to list any process)
```

or use a tool like netcat to see if you can start a tcp connection:

```
if nc -z [host] 9092; then
   echo "something is listening"
else
   echo "nothing is listening"
fi

# a direct way to change your loop is :
while ! nc -z localhost 9092; do
    sleep 1
done
```